# Align buttons or space between buttons in NavigationBar programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, storyboard

I have created navigation controller via storyboard interface and I have added 4 buttons programmatically on Navigationbar but I don't know how should I justify it would you please help me!

here is the picture:

[image: screenshot]

here is my code for buttons I know That I used **rightBarButtonItems** but I don't know what should I write instead!

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

  UIBarButtonItem *menuButton= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Menu" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone  
       target:self action:@selector(menu:)];

UIBarButtonItem *yearButton= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Year" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
target:self action:@selector(year:)];
 UIBarButtonItem *weekButton= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Week" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone 
 target:self action:@selector(week:)];
 UIBarButtonItem *reportButton= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Report" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone 
  target:self action:@selector(report:)];

NSArray *buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:menuButton,yearButton,weekButton,reportButton,nil];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = buttons;
}
```

Comment: Did you try setting frames for them?

Comment: @Nitish no I don't know how should I do that would you please help me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add flexible spacers between each of the buttons:

```
UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
```

Comment: thanks should I import any lib for that since I got error for *flexibleSpacer it's : Redefinition of flexibleSpacer .

Comment: No need to import anything, but don't use the same name twice.

Comment: then I write  UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpacer1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
but I got warning thai you used unused variable flexibleSpacer1

Comment: @justin This answer is correct, but the only other thing that I can think of that may make this work better would be to add the first two buttons as leftBarButtonItems and the second two as rightBarButtonItems and still using flexible spaces. (only if this doesn't work for you completely.

Comment: @MDT I added the warning picture check it please

Comment: @MDT I 'm really new to iOS would you please let me know how should I add rightbar button for 2 battons and left for another would you please write it in answer section

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle where is your answer?